# javascript window.addEventListener, overwritten the config of first element

Tags: javascript, overriding, config, addeventlistener

My apology, but really I don't know how to fix this code, or even how to search a fixed.

the problem is when I re-declared the function with own config value it overwrites the config of first declared. Any help please, it would help me a lot, please and thanks in advance.

Please fill free to edit my post, really I don't what to do.

```
var FX = (function(FX, $) {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
        FX.scrollTop.init({
            obj: $(".header--fixed"),
            from: 150
        }); 
        FX.scrollTop.init({
            obj: $(".sticky-left-nav"),
            from: 1600
        });     
    }); 
    /*----------------
    Scroll
    ----------------- */
    FX.scrollTop = {    
        config: {
            obj: '',
            from: 150,
            activeClass: 'scrolled'
        },  

        init: function(config) {
            $.extend(this.config, config);              

            var scrolledFromtop = $(window).scrollTop();
            //console.log(this.config.obj+'=>'+this.config.from);

            if(scrolledFromtop > this.config.from){
                config.obj.addClass('fixed');

                setTimeout(function(){
                    var config = FX.scrollTop.config;
                   config.obj.addClass(config.activeClass);
                }, 90);


            }else{
                var config = FX.scrollTop.config;
                config.obj.removeClass(config.activeClass);

                setTimeout(function(){
                    var config = FX.scrollTop.config;
                    config.obj.removeClass('fixed');
                }, 90);

            }   

        }       

    }
    return FX;
}(FX || {}, jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not re-declare init it is called twice successively and your original config object gets written over each time when init is called.

You could assign all need varibales for init to local variables and check for when they are not passed fallback back on your original defined configuration:

```
init: function(config) {

        var originalConfig = FX.scrollTop.config;

        var obj = config.obj ? config.obj : originalConfig.obj;
        var from = config.from ? config.from : originalConfig.from;
        var activeClass = config.activeClass ? config.activeClass : originalConfig.activeClass;

        var scrolledFromtop = $(window).scrollTop();
        //console.log(this.config.obj+'=>'+this.config.from);

        if(scrolledFromtop > from){
            obj.addClass('fixed');

            setTimeout(function(){
               obj.addClass(activeClass);
            }, 90);


        }else{
            obj.removeClass(activeClass);

            setTimeout(function(){
                obj.removeClass('fixed');
            }, 90);

        }   

}
```

Comment: thank you very much fro quick answer, I am newbie to this kind of coding.